# Debugging I2C Read

Tags: arduino, code, adafruit

I'm running code from [Adafruit_BuxIO] (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BusIO) which defines the function `write_then_read' as

```
bool write_then_read(const uint8_t *write_buffer, size_t write_len,
                       uint8_t *read_buffer, size_t read_len,
                       bool stop = false);
```

It then executes the following script:

```
void setup() {
uint8_t buffer[32];
buffer[0] = 0x0C;  // we'll reuse the same buffer
  i2c_dev.write_then_read(buffer, 1, buffer, 2, false);
  Serial.print("Write then Read: ");
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<2; i++) {
    Serial.print("0x"); Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX); Serial.print(", ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop(){
  
}
```

The results I got were surprising. "Write then Read: 0xB1, 0x4"

I had a couple of questions. Why is this code attempting to read 2 bytes if we are writing only 1 byte? Why does the output I capture not show 0x0C?

Answer (score 1):

I reads in the code comment why.

The read uses same buffer as write so 0x0C is not in the buffer because it is overwritten by data read from bus.

Also, without knowing anyhthing what you are communicating with, it is typical that you first write to a chip a command or register index what data you want to read from the device, and then you read the data out of it, which might be one, two, or any amount of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

2 bytes are read because you set *read_len* as *2* with:

```
i2c_dev.write_then_read(buffer, 1, buffer, 2, false);
```

0x0C is not shown, because with the same function, you have set the function to write the read value to *buffer*, so it overwrites the 0x0C.

You could introduce another buffer for the reading so 0x0C doesn't get overwritten:

```
uint8_t other_buffer[2];
i2c_dev.write_then_read(buffer, 1, other_buffer, 2, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried it, however the serial port didn't return the value from write command. "0xC1, 0x4". Which is interesting because I don't know where 0x4 is defined in the Arduino registers.